# Running two docker images in AWS task

Tags: amazon-web-services, openshift, amazon-ecs

Currently, we are using open-shift for application deployment. Application has 2 docker images, deployed in same pod. These two containers in open-shift communicate with each other. 
We are trying to migrate this application to AWS. The question is, what is right way to deploy these 2 docker images in AWS ECS task?

Comment: A right way depends on your use case. For example, you want to host on ECS EC2 instances or Fargate? Are the lifetime of containers tied to each other, or one can exist without other? Do they need to be publicly accessible? Do they run constantly, or on a recurrent schedule?

Comment: We are using  ECS EC2 instances. Containers can exist without each other.

Comment: Containers will run constantly.

Comment: Can you provided more details? Code, connection parameters, something? The best questions have such examples and include actions tried along with results of said actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can deploy up to 10 containers in an ECS task [1]. Containers can communicate with each other via localhost interface. You can setup volumes to share data between containers: [2]

Ref:

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/ecs-service.html#w540aab9d135b7b9

[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/docker-volumes.html#specify-volume-config